# R draw.triple.venn() scale circles

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I got some trouble scaling the Venn diagram with `draw.triple.venn()` on R. I guess it is a small thing, but I cannot find the answer.
Do someone know how to scale the circles ?

Here the command lines I used:

```
draw.triple.venn(area1 = nrow(sp1), area2 = nrow(sp3), area3 = nrow(sp4),
                 n12 =  nrow(subset(pval_test3, pval_test3$PValue_sp1<0.01 & pval_test3$PValue_sp3<0.01)), 
                 n23 =  nrow(subset(pval_test3, pval_test3$PValue_sp3<0.01 & pval_test3$PValue_sp4<0.01)), 
                 n13 =  nrow(subset(pval_test3, pval_test3$PValue_sp1<0.01 & pval_test3$PValue_sp4<0.01)), 
                 n123 = nrow(subset(pval_test3, pval_test3$PValue_sp1<0.01 & pval_test3$PValue_sp3<0.01 & pval_test3$PValue_sp4<0.01)),
                 category = c("Sp1_CAM", "Sp3_CAM", "Sp4_CAM"),
                 cex=3,
                 lty = 1,
                 lwd = 0.5,
                 fill = c("darkgreen", "orange", "mediumorchid"),
                 scaled = TRUE)
```

With the detail of the data:

```
sp1
            PValue_sp1   PValue_sp3   PValue_sp4
Aco007803 0.0000761000 4.297191e-02 4.030000e-05
Aco018093 0.0000016600 1.027826e-02 3.795107e-03
Aco013938 0.0000006830 6.530000e-13 4.310000e-09
Aco007734 0.0000153000 3.495795e-01 1.330000e-06
Aco004996 0.0063814087 5.454905e-01 2.514318e-03
Aco009967 0.0008453804 2.864100e-04 4.805802e-03

sp3
            PValue_sp1   PValue_sp3   PValue_sp4
Aco010025 0.1039756542 1.180000e-06 6.838790e-02
Aco016429 0.0482512443 1.069428e-03 6.083664e-03
Aco010095 0.1100983022 1.980850e-04 3.607129e-02
Aco013938 0.0000006830 6.530000e-13 4.310000e-09
Aco013935 0.2884582383 6.018554e-04 4.455669e-01
Aco009967 0.0008453804 2.864100e-04 4.805802e-03
Aco024818 0.2889005277 6.862406e-04 1.891679e-02

sp4
            PValue_sp1   PValue_sp3   PValue_sp4
Aco007803 0.0000761000 4.297191e-02 4.030000e-05
Aco018093 0.0000016600 1.027826e-02 3.795107e-03
Aco016429 0.0482512443 1.069428e-03 6.083664e-03
Aco013938 0.0000006830 6.530000e-13 4.310000e-09
Aco007734 0.0000153000 3.495795e-01 1.330000e-06
Aco002885 0.5065663636 9.802629e-01 5.633086e-03
Aco004996 0.0063814087 5.454905e-01 2.514318e-03
Aco009967 0.0008453804 2.864100e-04 4.805802e-03
Aco005989 0.1829716906 1.982196e-01 5.610000e-05
Aco007622 0.6341884350 1.010647e-01 6.367963e-04
Aco014488 0.4193623564 4.040470e-02 2.474636e-03

n12
            PValue_sp1 PValue_sp3   PValue_sp4
Aco013938 0.0000006830 6.5300e-13 4.310000e-09
Aco009967 0.0008453804 2.8641e-04 4.805802e-03

n23
            PValue_sp1   PValue_sp3   PValue_sp4
Aco016429 0.0482512443 1.069428e-03 6.083664e-03
Aco013938 0.0000006830 6.530000e-13 4.310000e-09
Aco009967 0.0008453804 2.864100e-04 4.805802e-03

n13
            PValue_sp1   PValue_sp3   PValue_sp4
Aco007803 0.0000761000 4.297191e-02 4.030000e-05
Aco018093 0.0000016600 1.027826e-02 3.795107e-03
Aco013938 0.0000006830 6.530000e-13 4.310000e-09
Aco007734 0.0000153000 3.495795e-01 1.330000e-06
Aco004996 0.0063814087 5.454905e-01 2.514318e-03
Aco009967 0.0008453804 2.864100e-04 4.805802e-03

n123
            PValue_sp1 PValue_sp3   PValue_sp4
Aco013938 0.0000006830 6.5300e-13 4.310000e-09
Aco009967 0.0008453804 2.8641e-04 4.805802e-03`enter code here`
```

And the graph produced:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dVtw.jpg)

But I would like to produced the following display (here "inkscaped", hand-made) for in a automated way for many data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0SmM.png)

Does anyone know how to produce the scaled image ?

Answer (score 0):

You should get the result you want by simply changing `scaled` to `FALSE`.